# Interfaces and Generated Binding Files

Tags: android, data-binding, interface, android-databinding

I am using data binding with a RecyclerView with multiple different layout files but a common view model.  Is there a way I can have the generated Binding files implement a common interface to simplify the following (working but ugly) code?

Given layout files such as:

```
R.layout.list_item_cat
R.layout.list_item_dog
R.layout.list_item_mouse
```

Within the ActionAdapter:

```
    @Override
    public ActionAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        @LayoutRes int layoutToInflate;
        switch (viewType) {
            case 0:
                layoutToInflate = R.layout.list_item_cat;
                break;
            case 1:
                layoutToInflate = R.layout.list_item_dog;
                break;
            case 2:
                layoutToInflate = R.layout.list_item_mouse;
                break;
        }
        return new ViewHolder(DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), layoutToInflate, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder.mBinding instanceof ListItemCatBinding) {
            ((ListItemCatBinding) holder.mBinding).setViewModel(mViewModelList.get(position));
        }
        else if (holder.mBinding instanceof ListItemDogBinding) {
            ((ListItemDogBinding) holder.mBinding).setViewModel(mViewModelList.get(position));
        }
        else if (holder.mBinding instanceof ListItemMouseBinding) {
            ((ListItemMouseBinding) holder.mBinding).setViewModel(mViewModelList.get(position));
        }
```

I know the above example isn't too bad, but it would be handy to be able to manipulate a set of Binding files, that share common things, without having to constantly check and cast their types, especially in more complex situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this article:

https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-recyclerview-db7c40d9f0e4#.l6soxb3sd

You can use:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.mBinding.setVariable(BR.viewModel,  mViewModelList.get(position));
    holder.mBinding.executePendingBindings();
}
```

Comment: `executePendingBindings()` might be worth calling as well.

Comment: Great stuff!  There's a very useful and relevant article too.

Answer (score 0):

You should override function getViewType(int position) for getting correct layout which you want to binding data